# Short story where employees agree to attach quasi-alive device to themselves, to keep them on-task when attention wanders

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Employees agree to attach a genetically engineered quasi-alive device to themselves, to keep them on-task when attention wanders during the day.

Written in a satirical company manual form. The creature may form a relationship with your spouse. George Saunders-style story, but I don't think it's by him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This sounds like a short story, is that correct?  When and where did you read this?

Comment: My first thought was The Beast from the Cleveland Depths, but that's mechanical, and more narrative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like *[The Daydreamer by Proxy](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2037222)* (2015) by Dexter Palmer.

Couldn't find a good summary or review written in English, so I used Microsoft Translator to convert [this review](http://gedankenecke.com/2017/05/the-daydreamer-by-proxy-von-dexter-palmer/) from German:

> **"The Daydreamer by Proxy" is a genetically engineered organism that Geneertech Corporation employees can voluntarily have planted. The organism not only increases the loyalty to the company dramatically. It also absorbs any distracting thoughts that arise during working hours.** As a result, he dramatically increases the performance of every employee who carries the organism with them. **In the short story, the reader will find the company's advertisement for the operation as well as an FAQ from the Geneertech Corporation and user questions.**
>
> The short story is a warning about the possible future degeneration of capitalism. It is in the nature of every company that they care about the efficiency of their employees in order to survive in the competition with competitors. Therefore, in all democratic welfare states there are regulations that restrict capitalist logics for the protection of workers. The “daydreamer” is an invention that is apparently not regulated, but rather tolerated by the legislature. It has advantages for the company as the employee becomes more efficient and loyal. The employee, in turn, can look forward to a higher chance of a raise. So is it a win-win situation?
>
> Of course not, otherwise the “Daydreamer” could only be found in a utopian short story collection. On the one hand, the organism can cause long-term damage. The body not only has to be adapted, the constant support of a living being also has psychological consequences. **Especially since the “daydreamer” absorbs many of the wearer's emotions and internalizes them over time. Since he can even learn to speak, this leads to bizarre situations such as flirting with his wife at night.** All of this can have fatal consequences in private life, makes the separation between work and life much more difficult and is much more invasive than, for example, the constant availability via mobile phone, which is lamented today.
>
> The most interesting thing about the (deliberately) technical documents presented in the short story are the subtle compulsions to choose a “daydreamer”. There is a direct threat of a dismissal if you do not opt ​​for the operation. Also, doubts from doctors and especially from employees are downplayed in a downright condescending way. The documents advise not to leave debates on forms of work to experts. In view of a procedure that changes the body and is almost unimaginable from today's perspective, which offers advantages (with the exception of the promotion decided by the company (!)) Exclusively for the employer side, Palmer encourages people to move away from the shrill debates about "digital capitalism" to think more publicly aboutwhat the limits of reasonableness in working life are and how far companies are allowed to go in their (legitimate) pursuit of efficiency.

Comment: Thanks.. that's the one.... I think this is where I read it.... The Best American Science Fiction and Fantasy 2016 Paperback... https://www.amazon.ca/Best-American-Science-Fiction-Fantasy/dp/0544555201